# Ionic v4 Statusbar text on iOS is not changing

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

So I've been building an cross-platform app with with ionic framework (Version 4)... but I've run into this strange issue where the text color on the status bar will default to white.

Setting the statusbar style doesn't seem to do anything at all... it'll temporarily change the statusbar, but then as soon as the launchscreen is finished, the text will always go back to white.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please put your statusbar code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've done some testing, and it seems that when system dark mode is enabled in iOS 13, the statusBar style methods (styleLightContent(),styleBlackOpaque(), etc) have absolutely no effect on the actual color of the statusbar.

It seems to be a bug with the plugin itself... specifically its inability to override dark mode status bar style.

Implementing the following code into the MainViewController.m completely disabled dark mode within the app, despite system dark mode being enabled. However, the statusBar could still be modified:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

For the moment, it seems as if there isn't really a simple solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can see i handled it by adding custom class and also the color attribute please try this so you can change color whatever you want

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar class="header-background-color">
    <ion-buttons slot="start" color="dark">
      <ion-menu-button color="dark"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      My App
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```